# Show that $(\textbf{R}^{n},d_{1})$ is indeed a metric space.

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, solution-verification

Show that $(\textbf{R}^{n},d_{1})$ is indeed a metric space.

**My solution**

The function $d_{1}$ is indeed positive-definite and symmetric on the variables $x$ and $y$. It remains to prove it satisfies the triangle inequality.

To begin with the demonstration, let us consider $a,b\in\textbf{R}^{n}$. Then we have that
\begin{align*}
|a_{1}| + \ldots + |a_{n}| + |b_{1}| + \ldots + |b_{n}| & = (|a_{1}| + |b_{1}|) + \ldots + (|a_{n}| + |b_{n}|)\\\\
& \geq |a_{1} + b_{1}| + \ldots + |a_{n} + b_{n}|
\end{align*}

Consequently, if we take $a = x - y$ and $b = y - z$, we conclude that $d(x,y) + d(y,z)\geq d(x,z)$.

Am I doing it correctly? Is there another way to solve this problem?

**Edit**

In this context, we define $d_{1}(x,y)$ as follows
\begin{align*}
d(x,y) = |x_{1} - y_{1}| + \ldots + |x_{n} - y_{n}|
\end{align*}

Comment: What do you define $d_1(x,y)$ as?

Comment: Let $x,y\in\textbf{R}^{n}$. We define $d_{1}(x,y)$ as
$$d_{1}(x,y) = |x_{1} - y_{1}| + \ldots + |x_{n} - y_{n}|$$

Comment: @EagerToLearn Please edit your question to include the definition.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I have edited it.